# virsh edit error: failed to get domain

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, virtual-machine-manager

I'm using KVM/QEMU and Virtual Machine Manager.

When I run in terminal `sudo virsh list --all` and the output is correct; it shows the one VM I have:

```
 Id   Name    State
------------------------
 -    win10   shut off
```

But then, when I'm running `sudo virsh edit w10` I get:

```
error: failed to get domain 'w10'
```

Why I'm gettting this error/how can I fix it? Also in Virtual Machine Manager GUI, when I try to edit the XML file, it discards any changes. The VM is fully functional. Also I have enabled XML editing in Virtual Machine Manager Preferences (Host is running Ubuntu 20.04).

Answer (score 2):

When running `sudo virsh list --all` you get the name `win10` instead of `w10`.

Try `sudo virsh edit win10` instead -- it should fix your issue, and if you don't have permission another answer may help.

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to improper permission for `virsh`. Either run via `sudo` or allow proper permissions using the following commands:

```bsh
sudo usermod -aG kvm ${USER}
sudo usermod -aG libvirt ${USER}
```